# laravel 5.8 responding with 500 internal server error on ajax request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5.8

I'm trying to send a `array` to mine controller to save in the data base if in this case I make the `array a string` it will save into the data base.
so when `data: {'mapData' : arrayAllDrawings},` it crashes (arrayAllDrawings beeing an array). But when it is hard coded like a string like this `data: {'mapData' : 'string'},` it would go thru and save in the database with `success message`

Error logs from `storage/logs` when the server throws the 500 internal server error

> [2019-03-28 08:40:09] local.ERROR: Array to string conversion {"userId":1,"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Array to string conversion at C:\Users\Merlijn\AppData\Roaming\Composer\Laravel Projects\Forum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Str.php:354)
>   [stacktrace]

I tried turning the `JS` array into 1 long string with in `JS` with `.toString()` but still gave the same error.

how the JS array looks like for example:

```
2: Array(2)
0: "{"type":"Feature","properties":{},"geometry": 
{"type":"Point","coordinates":[4.90694,52.385973]}}"
1: {type: "Name", Status: "Insert pointer name"}
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
3: "{"type":"Feature","properties":{},"geometry": 
{"type":"Point","coordinates":[4.90694,52.385973]}}"
length: 4
```

the javascript code ajax:

```
function saveInDb() {
        if (typeof arrayAllDrawings !== 'undefined' && arrayAllDrawings.length > 0) {
            $.ajax({
                method: 'POST', said in the route
                url: '{{ route('map.store') }}', gave in the route
                data: {'mapData' : arrayAllDrawings},
                success: function(response){ 
                    console.log(response);
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
                    console.log("AJAX error: " + textStatus + ' : ' + errorThrown);
                }
            });
        } else {
            alert('The map has nothing on it!')
        }
    }
```

the controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
//        dd($request);
//        $mapData = Input::get('mapData');
//        dd($mapData);
    if(request()->ajax()){

        $mapData = Input::get('mapData');
        $map = new Map;
        $map->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
        $map->map = $mapData;
        $map->save();

        return response()->json(['status' => 'succes', 'message' => 'saved in database','data' => $mapData]);

    } else {

        return response()->json(['status' => 'fail', 'message' => 'this is not json']);

    }
}
```

Comment: You can store the array in db using json_encode($mapData).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the javascript array into the json

```
JSON.stringify(arrayAllDrawings)
```

then you can get this is in the form of json and convert this json by

```
json_encode(json_decode($mapData,true));
```

and then store into the databse.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily manage this by convert array to string using :

```
json_encode($your_array); or serialize($your_array);
```

Reverse can be done :

```
json_decode($string); or unserialize($string);
```

with respect to above functions use.